# YQL (Yahoo Query Language) sort by date

Tags: yahoo, yql

I am trying to retrieve a particular attachment type (say 2500 such mails exist) from 01 Jan 2005 using YQL . The search statement is as follows:

```
SELECT hits FROM ymail.search WHERE attachmenttypes="pdf" and date-start = 1104537600
```

The result always starts from the latest mail. If I use the sort function as follows:

```
SELECT hits FROM ymail.search WHERE attachmenttypes="pdf" and date-start = 1104537600 | sort(field="hits.date", descending = "false")
```

the result is sorted but only a part of the total rows is returned. So 2 questions:

1) How do I request rows ordered by date?

2) Is there a way to retrieve all the rows at once? The documentation says we can retrieve 5000 rows at once  http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/paging.html . But this does not seem to be true. Even if I add "count = 3000" to the statement, still only a part of the total rows are returned.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I request rows ordered by date?

```
select * from {table} where query="apple" and order_by='relevance'
```

> Is there a way to retrieve all the rows at once?

```
select title from search.web(0) where query="pizza" limit 5000
```